# Set ImageSource From StaticResource in WPF, C# CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, resourcedictionary

I want to load my image (using c# CodeBehind in WPF) that is registered as a `StaticResource`, here is my `ResourceDictionary` :

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="SearchUser_NoUserPhoto" UriSource="/Shams.Win;component/Resources/Images/SearchUser/Account Disabled.png"></BitmapImage>
```

(I have added this resourceDictionary into App.Xaml and it works while being used in Xaml)

I have tried this code :

```
MyImage.Source = (ImageSource) Resources["SearchUser_NoUserPhoto"];
```

but it doesn't works for me. actually i have checked the `Resource` collection at run-time using `Immediate Window` but it has no element.

Comment: `Resources["MyFile.png"]` does *of course* not work, because "MyFile.png" is not a key in your ResourceDictionary (hint: the key is "SearchUser_NoUserPhoto"). Whether you use the Resources property, or the TryFindResource method doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I have read this line on another Question. at the next lines i mentioned that `Resource Collection` is empty for me !!!

Comment: So we should have guessed that you are probably *not* talking about the Resources property of the App class with the ResourceDictionary?

Answer (score -1):

This Code worked for me:

```
 AccountStat.Source = (ImageSource)TryFindResource("SearchUser_AccountEnable");
```

Using `TryFindResource` in `UserControl`s i could get access to my `ResourceDictionarie`s.